# Zend Framework on Zend Studio

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to Zend framework. When i have added a new page in script and a controller 
for that page is working perfetcly. I want to ask that is there any need for creating a
php file in public folder for each particular page.

Comment: can u explain ur question in bit detail. there is no need for adding php file in public folder other than index.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your index.php in the public folder acts as the entry point to your application.

In Zend Framework, Zend_Application and Bootstrap.php would be the one that actually starts and initializes your application but it's actually index.php that sets up the whole thing.

So to answer you question: Yes, you need index.php in public folder and no, you don't need to have any other php file in there for a ZF app to work

Comment: @Durga this is called the Front Controller Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Answer (score 1):

When you start getting more comfortable with the architecture of the framework, please take a look at this utility: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html

It's not exactly the greatest, most useful thing, but it does generate the basics for you so don't have to manually add view files, controllers, actions, etc.

It'll also help you understand where to put the necessary files and the convention it uses.

Answer (score 0):

No, you only need a index.php and a .htacess file. You can see the [ZF2 skeleton project](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) for a model of both of these files.